# CSS: Flexible width rollover horizontal list

Tags: html, css, navigation, listitem

I need some help. I am trying to make a horizontal navigation using only CSS and HTML. I don't want to have the menu labels as images, in case they change in the future. I have most of it working, but the issue is when I try to include an icon (image) for one of the LI. I want the icon to swap out as well. Here's my code so far:

CSS:

```
body {
padding: 50px;
margin: 0;
}

ul {
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px 0;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
float: left;
clear: left;
}

ul li {
float: left;
display: inline; /*For ignore double margin in IE6*/
margin: 0 9px;
}

ul li a {
text-decoration: none;
float:left;
color: #111;
cursor: pointer;
font: 14px/22px "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul li a span {
margin: 0px 10px 0px -10px;
padding: 1px 4px 1px 14px;
position: relative; /*To fix IE6 problem (not displaying)*/
float:left;
}

ul.green li a:hover  {
color: #fff;
background: url(images/green.png) no-repeat top right;
}

ul.green li a:hover span {
background: url(images/green.png) no-repeat top left;
}

ul.green li.home {
color: #111;
background: url(images/home-idle.png) no-repeat;
background-position: -1px;
padding-left: 18px;
}

ul.green li.home a:hover {
background: url(images/home-over.png) no-repeat -10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="green">
   <li class="home"><a href="#" title="Home"><span class="home">Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Archives"><span>Archives</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Rooms and Resources"><span>Rooms &amp; Resources</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Productivity"><span>Productivity</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Get Training"><span>Get Training</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="FAQs"><span>FAQs</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Like I said, here's what I am attempting do have happen:

1. Use CSS for the navigation (aside from the icon & background)
2. Change the background to a green, rounded corner rectangle (I used a
   .png image for the background)
3. Change the Home icon from blue to white

Please let me know if anyone can help.

Comment: That is hard to picture based on your description alone – would you mind sharing a sketch of what the design should look like?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a jsFiddle, and show what you're having the problem with--I don't see any reference to an image in your code example.